# React: component nos passed a value from the state to the props

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm working on a simple `Express/MongoDB/React` app.

I try to pass the `this.state.nearbyShops` array retrieved from an API in `App.js` to the component `NearbyShop` so that it can be displayed, but the array is null. It seems that it doesn't get assigned the value from the API (I'm sure the API returns the value based on my logs) but it must be something I misused or an asynchronous behaviour that caused this and I'm not aware of it...

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null
NearbyShop.render
C:/Users/yocalta/Documents/Projs/_rct/react-backend/client/src/NearbyShop.js:17
  14 | //return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}!</h1>;
  15 | //console.log(this.props);
  16 | var shops = this.props.shopsList;
> 17 | var cardShops = shops.map(function (shop) {
  18 |     return (
  19 |         <Card key={shop._id}>
  20 |             <CardImg top width="100%" src={shop.picture} alt="Card image cap" />
```

The `App.js` file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';
import NearbyShop from './NearbyShop';

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            lat: 0,
            long: 0,
            nearbyShops: null
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        var that = this;
        // Get the user's location (lat & long) in the state object
        const url = 'https://freegeoip.net/json/';
        axios.get(url)
            .then((response) => response.data)
            // Get the long & lat of the end-user
            .then((data) => that.setState({
                                lat: data.latitude,
                                long: data.longitude
            }))
            // Call our built-in Nearby API with the lat & long of the end-user
            .then(function (data) {
                axios.get('/nearby', {
                    params: {
                        lat: that.state.lat,
                        long: that.state.long
                    }
                })
                .then((response) => that.setState({
                    nearbyShops: response.shops
                }))
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            })            
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
            <h1>Shops List</h1>
            <NearbyShop shopsList={this.state.nearbyShops} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The `NearbyShop.js` file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {
    Card, Button, CardImg, CardTitle, CardText, CardGroup,
    CardSubtitle, CardBody
} from 'reactstrap';


class NearbyShop extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            shopsList: []
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        //var shops = this.props.shopsList;
        this.setState({ shopsList: this.props.shopsList});
    }
    render() {
        //return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}!</h1>;
        //console.log(this.props);
        //var shops = this.props.shopsList;
        var cardShops = this.state.shopsList.map(function (shop) {
            return (
                <Card key={shop._id}>
                    <CardImg top width="100%" src={shop.picture} alt="Card image cap" />
                    <CardBody>
                        <CardTitle>{shop.name}</CardTitle>
                        <CardSubtitle>Card subtitle</CardSubtitle>
                        <CardText>{shop.email}</CardText>
                        <Button>Fall in love</Button>
                    </CardBody>
                </Card>
            );
        })

        return (
            <CardGroup>
                {cardShops}
            </CardGroup>
    );
    }
}

export default NearbyShop;
```

Comment: One word: asynchronity. `this.state.nearbyShops` doesn't exist on first render so it's undefined in `NearbyShop`.

Answer (score 0):

Value of `nearByShops` is `null` until the result of `api` comes. So on first render it throws that error. You can get rid of this error by giving a default empty array value to `nearByShops`.

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            lat: 0,
            long: 0,
            nearbyShops: []
        }
    }
```

**OR**

you can check the existence of its value before iterating through it.

```
// If value of shops exist, then only map through it
var cardShops = shops && shops.map(function (shop) {...
```

Comment: I slightly changed the `NearbyShop` component. The thing is that I don't get my results displayed even though the error doesn't appear anymore.

Comment: @Sherlock I don't think there was any problem with the previous code apart from that error.  If you still want to make this change then you need to use `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method.